# My computer is really hot

Tags: 13.10

I've been dual booting for a week and when I installed the package lm-sensors, I noticed my PC is running at 60 -67 * C , how do I get it to run at a bearable rate?

Comment: Can you install i7z console application? It will give you the state of your cores, C1 means that core is running without any halts, and that will generate the most heat. If too many cores do that, you can try to see the culprit with console's top.

Comment: We need some more info about the hardware. Like what, CPU do you have? How many cores does it have? What GPU do you have? If it a laptop? What OS are you running?

Comment: Certainly, I was in a rush to type this. It's a Sony Vaio VPCJ115FX with Intel HD graphic s4000 Intel Core i3 M 350 @ 2.27GHz x 4

Comment: Oh and Dualbooting Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit